# hide specific gridview (Devexpress grid) field based on checkbox selection

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, aspxcombobox, devexpress-mvc

I have a gridview populated with data and based on Chekbox selection I would like to hide one field on editform.
any one can please guide on this,what would be better to hide the column on client side or server side code?, Please find the below code for your reference (below is 4 columns (4 fields) in devexpress Grid, when we select checkbox then one of column(Dropdown) should be hide.).

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" VisibleIndex="1"  Caption="Name">
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Email" VisibleIndex="2"  Caption="Email">
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="IsGraduate" VisibleIndex="3" Caption="Is Graduate ">
</dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Caption="Degree" FieldName="Degree" 
 ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4">
<PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="DegreeDataSource" TextField="Degree"  ValueField="Id">
</PropertiesComboBox>
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: The above looks like asp.net. Are you sure that the tag devexpress-windows-ui or devepxress-wpf  is relevant?

Comment: Yes , Pretty sure,I am working on Asp.net and using devepxress Grid.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but the [asp.net webforms](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/LinqDataSourceServerMode.aspx) looks close to your code above. The [mvc](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/DataBindingToLargeDatabase) code does not look like your code. On the [demo page for asp.net](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/demos.xml) is nothing mentioned about wpf. Are you using mvc or webforms?

Comment: i m using asp.net webforms

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use EditFormSetting visibility for necessary column? Look at the example below

```
        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="color" Caption="#" VisibleIndex="2" ReadOnly="True"
            Width="25px">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="ColoredStatusSource" TextField="name" ValueField="id"
                EnableSynchronization="False" IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains" ValueType="System.Int32">
            </PropertiesComboBox>
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you hide the column by using client side events to prevent callbacks.
Use the following codes as your guide:

```
    Protected Sub dgView_001_CellEditorInitialize(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs) Handles dgView_001.CellEditorInitialize

    If e.Column.FieldName = "IsGraduate" Then

        Dim chk As DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxCheckBox = New DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxCheckBox()

        chk = TryCast(e.Editor, DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxCheckBox)

        chk.ClientInstanceName = "chkIsGraduate"

        chk.ClientSideEvents.CheckedChanged = "function(s, e){ //if checked = true, hide column you want to hide }"

   ElseIf e.Column.FieldName = "Degree" Then

        Dim cmb As DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxComboBox = New DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxComboBox()

        cmb = TryCast(e.Editor, DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxComboBox)

        cmb.ClientInstanceName = "cmbDegree"

   End If

   End Sub
```

Take note that you should also assign a client instance name to the column you want to hide for you to access it in javascript. Hope this helps! :)